# Ajax with contentType application json always return Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a C# Web Api MVC 4 application running on a server to serve an IOS app.
But the method belows always return ERR 500.

```
$("#find_cep").click(function () {
    var version = "v1";
    $.ajax({
        url: version + "/Address/find_cep", /* URL que será chamada */
        type: 'POST', /* Tipo da requisição */
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: {
            id: version,
            method: "find_cep",
            params: {
                address_cep: $("#address_cep").val()
            }
        }, /* dados que setão enviados via POST */
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.dir(e);
            alert("Erro");
        },
    });
});
```

If removed the line with

```
contentType: 'application/json',
```

and the application works fine, but the IOS develop team says they need pass this contentType. I was looking for some kind of IIS config but didnt found.

Can someone help me please?

**EDIT**
Here is the controller code.

Note the LOG function. The log DOESNT log anything, so, I guess this code cannot be reached.

```
[HttpPost]
public object find_cep([FromBody]PostBase<Address> viewmodel)
{
    Log.SetLog(viewmodel.Params);
    Log.ErrorLog("LEandro barbicha");

    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    try
    {
        var address = DBExecuteSql.GetAdressByCEP(viewmodel.Params.address_cep);

        if (address.address_city != null)
        {
            return ReturnExpcted.ReturnResultExpected(stopwatch, true, address, "", "0", viewmodel.id);
        }
        throw new Exception(String.Format("Nenhum endereço encontrado para o cep {0}", viewmodel.Params.address_cep));
    }
    catch (SqlException se)
    {
        Log.ErrorLog(se.Message);
        return ReturnExpcted.ReturnResultExpected(stopwatch, false, new object(), se.Message, se.ErrorCode.ToString(), viewmodel.id);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.ErrorLog(e.Message); 
        return ReturnExpcted.ReturnResultExpected(stopwatch, false, new object(), e.Message, e.GetType().Name, viewmodel.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a server error. We need to see the server code.

Comment: can you find out the content-type of you actual request using the inbuilt tools of ie/chrome or fiddler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting a json content type but sending the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
If the content type has to be set to `application/json` then maybe you should be sending json instead.

```
$("#find_cep").click(function () {
    var version = "v1";
    $.ajax({
        url: version + "/Address/find_cep", /* URL que será chamada */
        type: 'POST', /* Tipo da requisição */
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            id: version,
            method: "find_cep",
            params: {
                address_cep: $("#address_cep").val()
            }
        }), /* dados que setão enviados via POST */
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.dir(e);
            alert("Erro");
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: the client isnt a C# app :(

Comment: just explaining, my sample is with an c# app, but with IOS app we get error too

Comment: @LeandroDeMelloFagundes are you sure you need the content type to be json, it it works without that then it probably shouldn't be there.

Comment: The IOS development team say they need it. The owner of project have anoter web services and 3 development teams. We are trying to do an Web Api to serve the IOS app. :(

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem I Fixed using following method

```
$("#find_cep").click(function () {
var version = "v1";
$.ajax({
    url: version + "/Address/find_cep", /* URL que será chamada */
    type: 'POST', /* Tipo da requisição */
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: {
        "id": version,
        "method": "find_cep",
        "params": {
            address_cep: $("#address_cep").val()
        }
    }, /* dados que setão enviados via POST */
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.dir(e);
        alert("Erro");
    },
});
```

});

You can see the parameters should show in "".